# How to get NSImage.Name in AppleScriptObj

Tags: macos, applescript, nsimage, applescript-objc

How to get [`NSImage.Name.cautionName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519835-cautionname)

in AppleScriptObj.
I tried:

```
set cautionName to aN of NSImage.Name
```

but that does not work.

Comment: It is a constant, so it would just be `current application's NSImageNameCaution`.

Comment: Really? Could you explain how the name "NSImage.Name.cautionName" is transfered to `NSImageNameCaution` 
i dont get that part? is that ObjC related?

Comment: Make sure you set the Apple documentation to show the Objective-C, not Swift, syntax.

Comment: AppleScriptObjC uses the Objective-C documentation, and also does not use dot notation.  Your documentation link was for Swift - changing it to Objective-C as mentioned by foo gives you that name, so it looks like you were just mixing them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you are after is `NSImageNameCaution`, which is a constant for the name of a system image.  Your example (and link) appear to be using `Swift`, changing the documentation language to `Objective-C` gives you the proper term.

**AppleScriptObjC** uses names from the **Objective-C** documentation (it also does not use dot notation), so it would be something like:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions

# get the name
set imageName to (current application's NSImageNameCaution) as text
# get the image
set theImage to current application's NSImage's imageNamed:(current application's NSImageNameCaution)
```

Comment: As I understand it, the question was posed like this: **get the name of the image**. Not a system image. To accomplish this, the code from **@red_menace** must end with the line **set imageName to theImage's | name | () as text**. But this was not done, as I understand it, on purpose so as not to repeat the solution I had already proposed (plagiarism).

Comment: @Robert Kniazidis - The provided link (although the name was from Swift) is for a global variable for the name of a (system) caution image, so I just went with that.

Comment: Re: @red_menace. Basically, your code is helpful enough, although it answers a different question. So I won't be offended if the OP accepts your answer.

Comment: Awesom thanks! Helps alot, didnt know its Swift

Answer (score 0):

It needs pipes to indicate that it is method

```
set cautionName to (anImage's |name|()) as text
```

NOTE: if the Image has not the associated name, then of course you will get missing value.

Comment: Is that correct: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519835-cautionname is a constant?